# T-SQL Merge when matched not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have a temp table containing email traffic data between domains as follows:

```
[EmailId|SendingDomainId|SendingDomainName|RecipientDomainId|RecipientDomainName]

[500|600|abc.com|700|pqr.com]

[501|601|def.com|701|stu.com]

[501|601|def.com|700|pqr.com]

[502|600|abc.com|700|pqr.com]
```

That is:

- email id 500 was sent from abc.com to pqr.com (1 sender, 1 recipient)
- email id 501 was sent from def.com to stu.com and pqr.com (1 sender, 2 recipients)
- email id 502 was sent from abc.com to pqr.com (1 sender, 1 recipient)

I am trying to compile a report which contains totals of emails sent between domains, to produce the following:

```
[SendingDomainId|SendingDomainName|RecipientDomainId|RecipientDomainName|Total]

[600|abc.com|700|pqr.com|2]

[601|def.com|701|stu.com|1]

[601|def.com|700|pqr.com|1]
```

I am trying this `MERGE` statement but the `UPDATE` part is not working. I am ending up with a final table containing the same rows as the source table.

```
MERGE #DomainsChord_TrafficData as T
USING #DomainsChord_DomainEmails AS S
ON (S.SendingDomainId = T.SendingDomainId AND
    S.RecipientDomainId = T.RecipientDomainId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET T.TotalEmails = T.TotalEmails+1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
    INSERT (SendingDomainId, SendingDomainName, RecipientDomainId,
            RecipientDomainName, TotalEmails)
    VALUES (S.SendingDomainId, S.SendingDomainName, 
            S.RecipientDomainId, S.RecipientDomainName, 1);
```

Table #DomainsChord_TrafficData is an empty temp table before the merge. After the merge, it ends up with the same data as the source table (#DomainsChord_DomainEmails)

Is anyone able to spot where i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need a `MERGE` at all in your case.  A simple `SELECT GROUP BY` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `MERGE` in your case.  You need a simple `SELECT` with a `GROUP BY` clause as follows:

```
SELECT SendingDomainId, SendingDomainName, RecipientDomainId, RecipientDomainName
     , COUNT(*) AS Total
  FROM #DomainsChord_DomainEmails
 GROUP BY SendingDomainId, SendingDomainName, RecipientDomainId, RecipientDomainName;
```

OUTPUT

```
SendingDomainId SendingDomainName RecipientDomainId RecipientDomainName Total
--------------- ----------------- ----------------- ------------------- -----------
600             abc.com           700               pqr.com             2
601             def.com           700               pqr.com             1
601             def.com           701               stu.com             1
```

A `MERGE` statement is to merge data from two a source into a target.  If your target (#DomainsChord_TrafficData) is empty, all data from source (#DomainsChord_DomainEmails) ends up in the target as you described.

Reference: MSDN [MERGE T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: That's right, seems like i was over-complicating things unnecessarily. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also as i replied to paulbarbin, I misunderstood how merging works exactly. A clear case of RTFM if there ever was one.

Answer (score 1):

If the table is empty before hand, then there is no Match for the update to execute, it is a NOT MATCHED and therefore the insert runs.

Comment: I see, clear. I misunderstood how merging works exactly. I thought it would iterate over all the rows individually, when in reality it's a join with the source table.